# How to apply css to asp.net LinkButton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I want to create a `css` block, which will apply `css class` to all `<asp:LinkButton>` throughout my web site.

- I can apply `css` for `<asp:TextBox>` throughout the website using below code single block.
           `input[type="text"] {width:150px;}`

Above code make `width=150px` to all asp textbox in my web site

The same way I want to write a `css` block which will apply to `<asp:LinkButton>` throughout the web site.

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<asp:LinkButton>` in asp.net renders `anchor(<a>)` tags in html then you can specify `css` for `anchor(<a>)` tag as:

```
a{
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> LinkButton control is a control just like a Button control along with
>   the flexibility to make it look like a Hyperlink.  *It implements an*
>   *anchor  tag* that uses only ASP.NET postback mechanism to post the
>   data on the server.

its same as  an anchor `<a>` tag so apply css style for

```
    a{
    //your style
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net there is inbuilt property called `CssClass`, you can use that. Here is the example how to use that:

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .lnkStyle
    {
        color: Red;
        font-size: 14;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" Text="Sample Link" CssClass="lnkStyle"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Best thing is that you can use and apply same class to multiple asp.net control using same way same class.

Hope it helps!